# Synchronizing android app with PHP code

Tags: android

I am creating an android app and I am using both global and local database. I am using PHP and MySQL for global database. How can I synchronize my android app with the PHP code(or website)?

Comment: @mansoulx- actually I hv no idea about dis, so I am asking how can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, but SO don't work like this ! [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) you'll understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anushka you should read this post

[Remote api call using android sdk](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-making-remote-api-calls/) in case you need to use data to show in your app

or, if you need to directly show your php page in android you could use  [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: Thanxs 4 dis link.It will definitely gonna help me.

Comment: This time this information is enough.First I will implement it,if I will stuck somewhere then definitely I will take your help.